# Uncaught (in promise) Error: FIRESTORE (4.10.1) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown relation: array-contains

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I get this error message in my browser when I call my web page
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: FIRESTORE (4.10.1) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown relation: array-contains`

I'm using Firestore. The funny thing is, that this works on my local machine and on the online dev machine, but on online production machine (clone of the dev machine) I get the error above.

Firestore introduced just some time ago a new way to query that lets you search within an array (see code below `where("userIds", "array-contains", userId)`.

All npm packages on the machines are the same version.

Any idea, where I can look for differences?

code

```
import "firebase/firestore"
import firebase from "firebase/app"

export function fetch({ userId }) {
  const db = firebase.firestore()

  return db.collection("/collection")
    .where("userIds", "array-contains", userId)
    .get()
    .then(querySnap => {
        return querySnap.docs
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
      throw err
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `array-contains` operator was introduced in [version 6.0.0 of the Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#6.0.0). According to the error message your production server is running 4.10.1, which doesn't support the array operators yet. To solve the problem you will need to update the server to Admin SDK version 6.0.0 or later.